# Creating NIC in Azure PS

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I want to create NIC in Azure and attach it to VM in that I will create in later step. I still get error, I think there is a bad value in subnetId but I have no idea why.

This is variable
`$subnetId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$targetVNET/subnets/$targetSubnetName"` 
This is line I try to create NIC
`$newNic = New-AZNetworkInterface -Name ($vmName + "_NIC") -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location -SubnetId $subnetId`

End I get such error
`Resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/target_vnet/subnets/Target_subnet1 referenced by resource | /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/test-vm_NIC was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same | region. StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request ErrorCode: InvalidResourceReference ErrorMessage: Resource | /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/target_vnet/subnets/Target_subnet1 referenced by resource | /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/test-vm_NIC was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same | region. OperationID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Then I try to attach NIC but it obviously fail as there is no NIC

`Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $newVM -ID $newNic`

Error
`Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.`

Could you help me find what causes this error?

Comment: It should be OperationID

Comment: Are you sure you’ve got the right subscription / resource group name / vnet name for the subnet? Have you hand-typed the names,  or did you cut&paste them from the Azure Portal to make sure they’re correct? Can you retrieve the vnet instance using ```Get-AzVirtualNetwork```? Do you definitely have at least *read* access to the objects from the account you’re running the script as (can you even *see* them in the Azure Portal)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my environment I got the same error like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/FICVcP4.png)]

This error may occur if you are using different virtual network associated from virtual machine make sure to use same vnet.

**You can make use of below script.**

```
# Set your variables
$subscriptionId = "XXXX"
$resourceGroup = "XXXX"
$location = "East US"
$targetVNET = "YourvmaAssociatevnetname"
$targetSubnetName = "SubnetName"
$vmName = "vmName"

# Construct subnet ID
$subnetId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$targetVNET/subnets/$targetSubnetName"

# Create NIC
$newNicParams = @{
    Name            = ($vmName + "_NIC")
    ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroup
    Location        = $location
    SubnetId        = $subnetId
}
$newNic = New-AzNetworkInterface @newNicParams

# Check if NIC creation was successful
if ($newNic) {
    Write-Host "NIC created successfully."

    # Retrieve the VM to attach the NIC
    $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName

    # Attach the NIC to the VM
    $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id = $newNic.Id
    Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
    Write-Host "NIC attached to VM '$vmName'."
} else {
    Write-Host "NIC creation failed."
}
```

***Output***:

[image]

Now I check in the portal NIC created and attached to my virtual machine successfully like below:

[image]

***Make sure to use vnet associated with that vm only.***

Comment: Hi Imran, thanks for help and clarification. I need a script to "move" VM from source VNET to target VNET. Idea is that script will read configuration of source VM, make snapshots of disks then delete source VM, create a NIC in target VNET, create a disk from OS snapshot, create VM from OS disk with all parameters from old VM, attach existing NIC from target VNET (which I have problem to create) to new VM. Rest steps is working, only this NIC creation fails. I will try to implement your code into my script and see if it's working.